# In Angular, module.controller, What does the array in the constructor mean?

Tags: angularjs

I see a lot of examples in Angular or controllers being created like

```
myApp.controller('DoubleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.double = function(value) { return value * 2; };
}]);
```

but despite searching everywhere, including in the Angular documentation, I can't find what the array in the parameter is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 1):

Its a annotation type for DI, you can check the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

**Inline Array Annotation**

```
someModule.factory('greeter', ['$window', function(renamed$window) {
// ...
}]);
```

Its a best practice to use this annotation because minifires are [broking](http://thegreenpizza.github.io/2013/05/25/building-minification-safe-angular.js-applications/) this annotation

```
someModule.factory('greeter', function($window) {
// ...
});
```

**UPDATE 1**

you can use 
[ng-min](https://github.com/btford/ngmin)  or [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)
with second annotation type

Comment: We don't have to practice it any more thanks to ng-min or ng-annotate http://blog.jerodsanto.net/2013/08/you-dont-have-to-annotate-your-angularjs-injections-anymore/

Comment: yes if U use ng-min or ng-annotate its not needed :)

Comment: Yes, it is also worth mentioning that this is required (unless using ng-min etc) so that when you minify your code variable shortening and renaming still works.

Comment: `...because minifires are broking this annotation` What do you mean?